# curl url with option location not working properly

Tags: curl, redirect, servlets, postman, httpresponse

I have a Java Servlet app deployed on WebLogic. The client makes a POST request say /WebServletApp/employee.
EmployeeServlet (doPost) receives it and for some specific condition i.e not always, the code makes a redirect call (GET).

`resp.sendRedirect("http://"+host+"/WebServletApp/defaultEmployee?r="+r);`

Now the above redirect URL /WebServletApp/defaultEmployee is served by DefaultEmployeeServlet (doGet).

If I use Postman client to send the first POST request. Redirect is followed and I get the expected response from the DefaultEmployeeServlet.

However, if I use curl -L from terminal to send the request, Redirect is not followed and I get the error

> HTTP method POST is not supported by this URL

**Why is this happening? '-L' or '--location' is supposed to help curl follow the redirect automatically by making the GET request to new location URI given by the redirect, right? What am I doing wrong here?**

**Why does Postman work and not curl?**

Here is the command output.

```
curl -iL --request POST '127.0.0.1:7001/WebServletApp/employee' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'firstName=Harshit' \
--data-urlencode 'lastName=Rajput' \
--data-urlencode 'emailId=harajput@gmail.com' \
--data-urlencode 'password=yolo!'
HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
Date: Tue, 18 May 2021 15:19:47 GMT
Location: http://127.0.0.1:7001/WebServletApp/defaultEmployee?r=18
Content-Length: 309
Content-Type: text/html
X-ORACLE-DMS-ECID: 176df710-a1ae-4554-9c30-5bf795293f7f-0000003a
X-ORACLE-DMS-RID: 0

HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
Date: Tue, 18 May 2021 15:19:49 GMT
Content-Length: 45
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
X-ORACLE-DMS-ECID: 176df710-a1ae-4554-9c30-5bf795293f7f-0000003b
X-ORACLE-DMS-RID: 0

HTTP method POST is not supported by this URL%
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out. Here is the solution if anyone comes wandering here.
(feel free to provide any other solution as well)

It's the 'request' option creating problem in following the redirects.

`curl -iL --request POST '127.0.0.1:7001/WebServletApp/employee'`

from 'man curl'

```
The method string you set with -X, --request will  be  used  for
all  requests,  which  if you for example use -L, --location may
cause unintended side-effects when curl doesn't  change  request
method according to the HTTP 30x response codes - and similar.
```

On removing the '--request' option and changing the curl command/syntax to
`curl --location -i 'localhost/WebServletApp/employee'`. I got it to work with the expected output.

```
curl --location -i 'localhost/WebServletApp/employee' \
--header 'User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.26.8' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'firstName=Harshit' \
--data-urlencode 'lastName=Rajput' \
--data-urlencode 'emailId=harajput@gmail.com' \
--data-urlencode 'password=yolo!'

HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
Date: Wed, 19 May 2021 06:34:48 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.46 (Unix)
Location: http://localhost:80/WebServletApp/defaultEmployee?r=18
Content-Length: 305
X-ORACLE-DMS-ECID: d0da2790-1291-46f2-b9f4-52355bbc9c1a-00000019
X-ORACLE-DMS-RID: 0
Content-Type: text/html

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 19 May 2021 06:34:50 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.46 (Unix)
Content-Length: 252
X-ORACLE-DMS-ECID: d0da2790-1291-46f2-b9f4-52355bbc9c1a-0000001a
X-ORACLE-DMS-RID: 0

<html><body><p> firstName employee:: default fname</p><p> lastName employee:: default lname</p><p> firstName employee:: default email</p><p> firstName employee:: default passwd</p><p> Time :: 1621406090386</p><p> Random number r :: 18</p></body></html>%
```